# Como verificar se o programa já esta executando em C#

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de verificar se já existe uma instancia do programa em execução, para que caso eu clique no ícone do programa ele não chame uma nova instancia do programa e sim abra o programa já ativo. Preciso do código em C#.

Comment: Procurar pelo processo não ajuda?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a classe [`Mutex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx). Processos podem ter nomes iguais e isso pode acabar atrapalhando. Principalmente num contexto onde não se tem controle completo da estação de destino.

```
using System.Threading;    

class Program 
{
    // name é o identificador único da aplicação
    static Mutex _mutex = new Mutex(true, name: "d4709732-f5aa-404f-ba0e-a0a8a4201ff6");

    static void Main() 
    {
        if (_mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true)) 
        {
            try 
            {
                InicializarAplicacao();
            }
            finally 
            {
                _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Já existe uma instancia do programa em execução");
        }
    }
}
```

---

A título de conhecimento é possível procurar pelo processo com o mesmo nome do processo atual. **Lembrando que** isso vai causar problemas se existir um outro processo com o mesmo nome.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    Process processoAtual = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

    var processoRodando = (from proc in Process.GetProcesses()
                           where proc.Id != processoAtual.Id &&
                                 proc.ProcessName == processoAtual.ProcessName
                           select proc).FirstOrDefault();

    if (processoRodando != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Já existe uma instancia do programa em execução");
        return; 
    }

    InicializarAplicacao();
}
```

Ou

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Nome do processo atual
    string nomeProcesso = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;

    // Obtém todos os processos com o nome do atual
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(nomeProcesso);

    // Maior do que 1, porque a instância atual também conta
    if (processes.Length > 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Já existe uma instancia do programa em execução");  
        return;
    } 

    InicializarAplicacao();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Você também pode fazer uso do [`Mutex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx)
Obs: no 2º parâmetro (*Name*), eu gerei um GUID.

```
using System.Threading;


static class Program {

    static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, name: "{37BF258D-FA21-476C-9E6A-0FE832F984C2}");

    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true)) {
            try {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
            finally {
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Este programa já está sendo executado!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, esta é a maneira mais precisa. Aplicações podem ter o mesmo nome de executável, porém o mutex (se a aplicação puder garantir unicidade de nome) será exclusivo.

Comment: Já tive um problema de ambiguidade no nome do executável. Nunca mais depois do Mutex ;)

Comment: Essa é a forma correta, a forma acima, não funciona se o programa for utilizado em um windows terminal server.

Answer (score 3):

```
 public partial class App : System.Windows.Application
    {
        public bool IsProcessOpen(string name)
        {
            foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses()) 
            {
                if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(name))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get Reference to the current Process
            Process thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            if (IsProcessOpen("name of application.exe") == false)
            {
                //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Application not open!");
                //System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
            }
            else
            {
                // Check how many total processes have the same name as the current one
                if (Process.GetProcessesByName(thisProc.ProcessName).Length > 1)
                {
                    // If ther is more than one, than it is already running.
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Application is already running.");
                    System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
                    return;
                }

                base.OnStartup(e);
            }
        }
```

[Resposta cópia.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722198/checking-if-my-windows-application-is-running/4722300#4722300)

Comment: Seria interessante adicionar uma explicação para sua resposta.